# Magento2: I want to apply SKU filter in product layered navigation

Tags: magento2, filter

I want to add the additional filter on product list page on frontend and product list should be filter by some SKU as well.
I am able to filter using SKU but filter is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you head to Stores -> Attributes -> Product then search for SKU. You're able to edit the store front properties in there. Such as adjust search weight etc. If you're referring to layered navigation, this isn't possible without a custom approach. "Can be used only with catalog input type Yes/No, Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price.
Price is not compatible with 'Filterable (no results)' option - it will make no affect on Price filter."

Comment: I am talking about layered navigation filter.....what are the files I need to update? any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why would you want to filter by SKU? It's a unique value?